# R package (twitteR) returns short URL destination rather than URL text

Tags: r, twitter, web-scraping

I'm trying to pull the text of a URL from a twitter feed--about 3,000 of them--via the twitteR package in R. Specifically, I want the longitude and latitude data contained in the URLs in this tweet: 
https://twitter.com/PGANVACentralCh/status/885702041275969536

However, the twitteR package scrapes out the short form URL destination instead:
e.g.: https://t dot co slash Y0pGeSiVFJ

I *could* follow all 3,000 links individually and copy and paste their URLs and then transform them to longitude and latitude, but there has to be a simpler way?

Not that it matters for this particular problem, but I am getting the tweets via this code:

```
#
library(twitteR)                       
library(httr) 
#
poketweets <- userTimeline("PGANVACentralCh", n = 3200)
poketweets_df <- tbl_df(map_df(poketweets, as.data.frame))
write.csv(poketweets_df, "poketweets.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get hold of the `entities.url.expanded_url` value from the Tweet object. I do not believe that the status objects returned by twitteR support that (the [status object fields](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9/topics/status-class) are only a subset of the Tweet JSON values). Additionally, twitteR is now deprecated in favour of [rtweet](http://rtweet.info/).

Using rtweet, you can modify your code:

```
poketweets <- get_timeline("PGANVACentralCh", n = 50)
head(poketweets)
```

You'll find there's a urls_expanded field in each Tweet dataframe that you can use.

Comment: I'm going to try this, but for now I can't seem to get rtweet to connect to Twitter's API? I'm getting this error:



      Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = 
      self$params$permission,  : 
        Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

Comment: Yeah you need to modify your Auth code for rtweet's method too - there is a page in the docs on that.

Comment: I've been following their instructions but don't seem to be making much headway. I'll keep at it. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out! Wasn't using the callback URL function. I think I'm good now. Thanks!

In fact, just ran it and got the info I wanted. perfect. thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you figured it out.